# mergetool with no prompt

Tags: git, prompt, mergetool

I am using mergetool to enhance modifications of files regarding merge conflicts. I wish to use mergetool without prompting from me.

```
See 'git mergetool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git mergetool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
tortoisemerge emerge vimdiff
Merging:
mergefile.txt

Deleted merge conflict for 'mergefile.txt':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: deleted
Use (m)odified or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort?
```

Comment: I think there is a configuration setting for trusting the exit code from the merge tool application, perhaps this one will make it behave like you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
git config mergetool.prompt false
```

This will disable the prompt to use the merge tool each time a merge conflict happens.

However, that specific output is **not** prompting you to use a merge tool. A merge tool isn't used when the merge conflict is a **deleted merge conflict**, i.e. where a file has been modified on one side and deleted on the other side. There'd be nothing to compare with a merge tool since one side would be completely empty. The solution is to choose an option using m/d/a on the command line to answer that question.

Comment: I used the command you suggested. But I got an error stating that "error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
U       mergefile.txt
error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict."

Comment: @Pavithra What is your merge tool set to?